# Count set bits in float in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, bit-manipulation

This is an interview question: how to count set bits in float in Java ? I guess I should not know the bit representation of float to answer this question. Can I just convert a float to a byte array somehow? I can use the Java serialization but it looks like overkill.

Comment: You have more than ten questions you haven't accepted. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Float class has an:

```
    public static int floatToIntBits(float value)
```

method that returns  a representation of the specified floating-point value according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout.

So you can get the bits with this method, then count which ones are set.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Once you have an int representation, there a lots of ways to count them. Many of them are described [here](http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Integer.bitCount(Float.floatToIntBits(value))
```

Having said that it's a very bad interview question...... seems to rely more on knowing specifics of the Java API which is *not* what you should be using as a basis for hiring. You want someone who understands the principles and knows how to look the details up when needed, not someone who just memorises APIs.

Answer (score 1):

As well as Java API methods, there's [various bit hacks hiding here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) that you could use as well, although how well they translate to the Java world I don't know (or for those that do, whether they're any more efficient that calling APIs). See the 'Counting bits set' section.